# Getting TypeError FlatList React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I want to navigate to another screens when user click on the item of the flatlist but keeps getting the same error.

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`

I created a project on snack.expo to give it a try on moving between screens and it works. Here's the link https://snack.expo.io/ad5yaIPIo

But whenever I tried to implement on my project, I'm getting the same error. Need help.

```
AuditList.js // Child Component

const AuditList = ({navigation}) => {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  const ItemRender = ({item}) => {
    const backgroundColor =
      item.id === selectedId ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
    return (
      <AuditItem
        item={item}
        onPress={() => {
          setSelectedId(item.id);
          navigation.navigate('Audit Details'); // Here's the navigation to go to another screens
        }}
        style={{backgroundColor}}
      />
    );
  };
  return (
    <AuditContainer>
      <FlatList
        data={DataList}
        renderItem={ItemRender}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        extraData={selectedId}
      />
    </AuditContainer>
  );
};
```

```
SiteAudit.js // Parent Component

const InProgress = () => {
  return <AuditList />;
};

const Completed = () => {
  return <AuditList />;
};

const SiteAudit = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Screen name="In Progress" component={InProgress} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Completed" component={Completed} />
  )
}
```

```
StackNavigation.js // Navigate To Another Screens

const StackNavigation = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Site Audit">
        <Stack.Screen name="Site Audit" component={SiteAudit} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Audit Details"
          component={AuditDetails}
          options={{
            headerLeft: () => (
              <LeftNavigationButton navigationProps={navigation} />
            ),
            headerTitle: (props) => <HeaderLogo {...props} />,
            headerStyle: {
              height: 150,
              backgroundColor: '#212529',
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
              borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
              shadowColor: '#212529',
              shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 2,
              },
              shadowOpacity: 0.7,
              shadowRadius: 3.84,
              elevation: 5,
              alignSelf: 'center',
            },
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

**EDIT**

```
Routes.js // Main Navigation

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={RootTheme}>
      {user ? (
        <>
          <DrawerNavigation />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <AuthStack />
        </>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

How could I call the `AuditDetails` in my main navigation? Let's assume that my `StackNavigation.js` is a navigation for `AuditDetails`

Comment: Where you render `AuditList ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `AuditList` is not rendered **directly** as a screen by your navigation system ((`InProgress` component does)) ... `navigation` object is not injected auto. into your component prop

So you either

- use `useNavigation` hook.

  ```
   import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
   const navigation = useNavigation();
  ```

OR

- pass the `navigation` object down to your `AuditList` component.

**EDIT**

```
const InProgress = ({ navigation }) => {
  return <AuditList navigation={navigation} />;
};
```

**Edit 2**
There's a space in your name ... remove it, cause that's the routeName that's to be used for navigation

```
 <Stack.Screen
          name="Audit Details" // <-- here
```

*The same issue does exist in other routes*

Comment: My ```AuditList``` component is rendered on parent component which I didn't provide here. Parent component in my case purposely just to render the ```<Tab.Screen>``` component. I'm using this ```const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();```

Comment: Could you edit your Q with your TabNavigator?

Comment: I'm getting another error on payload. Fyi, I've already created a page screen for ```Audit Details```.

The error ```The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"AuditDetails"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'AuditDetails'?```

Comment: Sir, I think the code I provided is a bit confusing. See the edited question.

Comment: Thank you sir, I figured it out regarding the navigation. Thanks for your help!